# Proving $n\not\in n$ for $n\in\mathbb N$ without regularity

Tags: set-theory, axioms, foundations

Is there a way to prove in ZF theory without regularity axiom $\forall n\in\mathbb N$, $n\not\in n$? At this point, I haven't proved yet that $\mathbb N$ is a well-ordered set, so a proof of the well-order shall not use $\forall n\in\mathbb N, n\not\in n$.

I tried induction, but I struggle with the recursive step as I only found that $n\not\in n\Leftrightarrow n\neq n^+$.

Comment: What is your definition of $\mathbb{N}$?  The intersection of all sets that contain $\emptyset$ and are closed under $x\mapsto x\cup\{x\}$?

Comment: @EricWofsey That's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can prove that the relation $\in$ is transitive on $\mathbb{N}$.  That is, if $x,y,z\in\mathbb{N}$ satisfy $x\in y$ and $y\in z$, then $x\in z$.  The proof of this is quite straightforward by induction on $z$.  (For the induction step, if $x\in y$ and $y\in z^+$ then either $y\in z$ so $x\in z\subseteq z^+$ by the induction hypothesis or $y=z$ so $x\in z\subseteq z^+$.)

Now let us prove that $n\not\in n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ by induction.  The base case $n=\emptyset$ is trivial.  In the induction step, suppose we know $n\not\in n$ and we wish to show $n^+\not\in n^+$.  Well, if $n^+\in n^+=n\cup\{n\}$ then either $n^+\in n$ or $n^+=n$.  In the first case, we have both $n\in n^+$ and $n^+\in n$ so by transitivity $n\in n$, contradicting the induction hypothesis.  In the second case, we have $n\in n^+= n$, again contradicting the induction hypothesis.

Comment: "Induction" is iff "well ordered"

Comment: @markvs You don't need well-order to prove induction, what's your point?

Comment: This proof is so clear, I can't believe how hard it was to find it online or by myself. Trying to prove the apparently obvious things, I understand now why logicians were deemed crazy.

Comment: @Maxence1402: Induction and well order are equivalent. If you use one, you can use another.

Comment: @markvs This has yet to be proved here.

Comment: @markvs: Well-ordering is trivially equivalent to *strong* induction.  In this context we only have weak induction (which is basically immediate from the definition of $\mathbb{N}$ used here) and have not yet proved strong induction.

Comment: OK, since the OP is ha[[y with it, I am not going to argue.

Answer (score 1):

We will demonstrate that $\in$ is well-founded on $\mathbb{N}$.

Suppose we have some $W$. Suppose that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, if (for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$, if $j \in k$ then $j \in W$), then $k \in W$. I claim that $\mathbb{N} \subseteq W$.

To prove this, we will show that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n \subseteq W$. We do this by induction on $n$.

In the base case of $n = \emptyset$, the claim that $n \subseteq W$ is immediate.

For the inductive step, suppose that $k \subseteq W$. We wish to show that $k \cup \{k\} \subseteq W$. To do so, it suffices to show that $k \in W$, since we already know that $k \subseteq W$ by the inductive hypothesis. Now consider some arbitrary $j \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $j \in k$. Then $j \in k \subseteq W$, so $j \in W$. Therefore, we see that $k \in W$ as claimed. The induction is complete.

In particular, then, given some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $n \in n \cup \{n\} \subseteq W$, so $n \in W$. This completes the proof that $\in$ is well-founded on $\mathbb{N}$. $\square$

Now suppose that $R$ is well-founded on set $S$. Suppose we had some $s \in S$ such That $s R s$. Then define $S’ = S \setminus \{s\}$.

Now consider some arbitrary $w \in S$. Suppose that for all $w’ \in S$, if $w’ R w$ then $w’ \in S’$. Now suppose $w \in \{s\}$; that is, suppose $w = s$. Then $w \in w$, so in particular, $w \in S’$. But then $w \notin \{s\}$; contradiction. Therefore, $w \notin \{s\}$. Thus, $w \in S’$.

Therefore, by well-foundedness, $s \in S \subseteq S’$. Then $s \in S’$. Contradiction. Therefore, we must in fact have had $\neg (s R s)$. $\square$

Combining these two facts completes the proof.